# Google Indexing API Batch Request AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'events'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

I am trying to use the Google Indexing BATCH Requests but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code: There's no proper documentation, So I have modified it myself. However, It's generating errors.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build 
SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"

# service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
JSON_KEY_FILE = "service_account_file.json"

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('indexing', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

def insert_event(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
      print(exception)
    else:
      print(response)

batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=insert_event)
batch.add(service.events().quickAdd(url="URL HERE", type="URL_UPDATED"))
batch.add(service.events().quickAdd(url="URL HERE", type="URL_UPDATED"))
batch.execute(http=http)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sofia\Downloads\ss.py", line 23, in <module>
    batch.add(service.events.quickAdd(url="https://jobsinwales.org/jobs/united-kingdom-jobs/co-225/", type="URL_UPDATED"))
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'events'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few references you may find useful:

Here's an explanation of how to [batch requests](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/batch.html). There's reference material for the python client library at [Indexing API reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/indexing_v3.html).

See also [Indexing API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart) (all the reference docs are dynamically generated from the [same place](https://developers.google.com/discovery)).

Minor updates made to your code:

```
batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=insert_event)
batch.add(service.urlNotifications().publish(
    body={"url": "URL HERE", "type": "URL_UPDATED"}))
batch.add(service.urlNotifications().publish(
    body={"url": "URL HERE", "type": "URL_UPDATED"}))
batch.execute()
```

Secondly, though this should work as is, oauth2client is deprecated. You may want to consider upgrading to the [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) library.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
JSON_KEY_FILE = "service_account_file.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```